# Mirror applications in IIS on another failover server

Tags: web-hosting, iis, mirror

Apologies for my lack of knowledge int his area, but hopefully you guys can help.

I have approx 20 .Net MVC applications hosted on a dedicated 2016 server. These sites are all linked to a database on another server.

I then have two failover servers with the same spec. One for the web applications and the other for the databases.

In regards to the servers the web applications are hosted on I have 3 queries:

1. Is there a way to copy the entire set up (iis settings, files, folders etc) to the new server, without having to set up every site individually again?
2. Once the failover server has been set up initally, how do I ensure that these applications are kept in sync with the production server. i.e. when a file is changed or image uploaded on the production server the change is automatically replicated on the failover server. (ideally it would be set and forget)
3. Lets say the production server goes down...what is the best way to actually failover to the failover server. Would the DNS setting for each application have to be updated?